# jQuery Datepicker with Separate Year and Month Navigation

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, daterangepicker

I have a specific new requirement related to date picker. I've gone through a lot of date time pickers on different links in Google but I've yet to find one that matches my requirements.

I am attaching mockup below.

When the date input field is clicked, it should show this normal calendar.

[image: Normal Calender]

If user has to select a very old year, user should just click on year and it will show years as below and a separate year navigation should be available for immediate previous or next selection.

[image]

Similarly for Months selection, user can simply click on month and it will list months and a separate month navigation should also be available.

[image]

The closest I've found is [Air DatePicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/) and [Bootstrap DatePicker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Configurable-Date-Picker-Plugin-For-Bootstrap/) but they both don't support separate navigation for Year and Month.

Should I try to develop this on my own from scratch or is there any other library that support these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonable requirements for a user age selector etc.

I've not done a extensive search on currently available datePickers that meet your requirements. I definitely recall seeing / using one as a user age selector (Can't recall its name or the website I used it on, and most of the sites have migrated from datepicker to datepicker so the code is likely already lost in the vaults of git)

That said I took a look at **Air DatePicker**, looks rather slick, I see why you mentioned it.

I have made a couple of tweaks to its **datepicker.js** and **datepicker.css** files, seems to able to do what you require with some changes.

As you can see below I split the title into 3 's. Plunker contains the modified files.

I would recommend you use something like **WinMerge** and compare the [air datepicker original files](https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/tree/master/dist), to my changed ones on plunker. Should be easy to further extend it as you need.

My only reservations doing this would be:

- As improvements and bug fixes happen to Air Datepickers new versions you would need to modify then again. Or submit this request to its creator.
- If you use some of the other 'air datepicker' options available the results could be unexpected.

Developing your own sounds like a heavy task, rather take your favorite plugin visually, already containing the majority of features you require, and attempt to extend it. My extension of air date picker now is a hack in my mind. Depending on the air date picker options you require it could be coded better.

Good luck.

[plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gmBeaJhtjWFj3pjO5iIQ)

```
var template = '' +
    '<div class="datepicker--nav-action" data-action="prev">#{prevHtml}</div>' +
    '<div class="datepicker--nav-title-left">#{titleLeft}</div>' + 
    '<div class="datepicker--nav-title-centre">#{titleCentre}</div>' + 
    '<div class="datepicker--nav-title-right">#{titleRight}</div>' +
    '<div class="datepicker--nav-action" data-action="next">#{nextHtml}</div>',
```

Comment: I am using Air DatePicker with your changes. Works like charm. Thanks @RoryGS.

Comment: A pleasure, happy it works for your requirements. I like how Air DatePicker presents the year / month options. Have added it to my list of to use plugins for some products.